# Edit checkout success html file : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am editing file:

```
/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml
```

but Nothing changed. What should I do?

Also I installed a theme which not have a success.phtml. that means enforce me to edit the core file(the path above). Is there is a solution to edit in the theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to override file into your theme,
After overriding file you can change your custom code using theme file,

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml
```

Comment: I copied  the file `success.phtml` from `/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml` and added into the path you mentioned and edited it, but nothing changed. is there is something wrong?

Comment: Did you clear or flush cache ?

Comment: You have to just clear cache and check.

Comment: yes, I cleared the cache.

Comment: You have to deploy static-content.

Comment: Also. I deployed the content.

Comment: Sorry..no need to deploy static content as its a phtml file. Just clear the cache and it should work. Clear browser cache as well.

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: I did the same thing and it worked at my end. app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58958/discussion-between-sejal-shah-and-jsparo30).

Comment: I cleared the cache for magento and browser, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Jsparo30 Update question with your theme path where you put success.phtml file